# What is GLaDOS's name an acronym for?

Tags: portal-series

I remember reading somewhere that the name "GLaDOS" is short for something but it didn't say what. Does anyone know what "GLaDOS" is short for?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

GLaDOS is short for: **Genetic Lifeform and Disk Operating System**

[Source](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/GLaDOS)